# How to show a set of functions is or is not an open set on the sup-metric?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

This is an excerpt from my text:

> The set $G$ of functions $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $|g(x)|\le 1$ for all $x$ is not an open set in the sup-metric space. For instance, consider the function $g(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}\tan^{-1}(x)$: There is no positive $\epsilon$ such that $B_\epsilon(g)\subseteq G$.

I don't understand why the last statement is true. So I am attempting to prove it myself.

I am able to show that $g(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}\tan^{-1}(x)$ is in $G$. So, the next step is to attempt to construct an open ball around $g(x)$ and realise that no matter what radius, $\epsilon$ I choose, that open ball will not be in $G$.

So, for some $\epsilon>0$,

$B_\epsilon(g)=\{f(x)\in G  :\, d_\infty(f(x),g(x))<\epsilon \}$.

Where $d_\infty(x,y)$ is the sup-metric.

I don't see how to get a contradiction from the definition of $B_\epsilon(g)$. Please help.

In fact, I am not even sure what an open ball of a set of functions looks like. I feel that the method to show that the open ball is a or is not an open set should be analogous to doing the same in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but I just don't see a connection.

So, can I also have an example when the open ball of a set of functions is open and how to show it is true? The treatment of my text on topic is very scarce.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\lim_{x \to \infty} |g(x)|  =1$,  and let $\epsilon>0$.

Let $f(x) = (1+ {1 \over 2}\epsilon\operatorname{sgn} g(x))g(x)$. Then $f \in B(g,\epsilon)$, but since $\lim_{x \to \infty} |f(x)|  =1+ { 1\over 2} \epsilon$, we see that $f \notin G$ (since for some finite $x$, we have $|f(x)|>1$).

We see that $\lim_{x \to \infty} {2 \over \pi} \arctan x = 1$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The function $f(x) \pm \epsilon/2$ is inside the ball centered around $f$ with radius $\epsilon$ according to the definition of sup norm. So what happens if your function either takes on the value $\pm 1$, or approaches the value $\pm 1$ as $x \to  \pm \infty$ or $x \to c$ for some $c$? Or more generally, what if you have a function that takes on various values $\pm (1 - \delta_i)$ for a sequence $\delta_i$ that goes to 0?

Answer (score 0):

An $\epsilon$ neighbourhood around a function $f$ is the set of all functions $g$ such that $|f(x)-g(x)|<\epsilon$ for ALL $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Observe that, geometrically, what happens is that $f=(2/\pi)\tan^{-1}(x)$ tends towards $\pm 1$ in the extremes. Consider the function $g$ define by 
$$ g(x)=f(x)+\epsilon/2.$$
By our definition, $g$ is in the $\epsilon$ open neighbourhood of $f$. However, one can always find $x_0$ such that $1-f(x_0)<\epsilon/2$ (since $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=1$. But in this which case we have $g(x_0) > 1$.

And this is true for ALL $\epsilon$. Which means that there cannot be any open $\epsilon$-neighbourhood around $f$ contained in the set of $\{f\  \mid |f(x)|\leq 1\; \text{for all }x\in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Picture:

[image]

The key point of an $\epsilon$-nbhd is that the all the functions whose graphs lie inside the shaded area, are a part of this nbhd. As you can see, since $f$ aproaches $\pm 1$, you can always find a function whose graphs is in this shaded area but it leaves the $\pm 1$ bound.

Any open set in the sup metric can be express as a union of these $\epsilon$-nbhds. In other words, they are a basis for the sup topology.

Comment: Is it possible to illustrate this with a sketch? And what about an example of a set of functions that is an open set?

Comment: by definition, an open $\epsilon$-neighbourhood is open... in fact is a basis for the topology. I

Comment: Please don't ask for more. Make en effort to understand the definitions. Consider accepting the answer if you find this solves your question (and the additional question you just made in the comments).

Comment: There is you sketch.

Answer (score 0):

When I imagine an open ball in this space, I try to have in mind the graphic of the center function and a strip $2\epsilon$ width around it. Any function whose graph is strictly contained in this strip is in the ball.

Now try to imagine the strip around $\tan^{-1}$ graph. Must this strip (no matter how narrow is) go out the limit at $y=1$? Does the fact that
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\tan^{-1}(x)=1$$
have anything to do with it?